# Electronically sign a pdf

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, vba, pdf

I want to add a signature to given x,y coordinate of a PDF(Always the same coordinates), the problem is can not figure out how to do this programatically. Ideally i would like do this from vba in excel, but i could fire any other script to do it.

The sources i found so far are [adobe sdk](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FJS_Dev_RMA%2FReview_Markup_and_Approval.htm&rhsearch=sign&rhhlterm=sign&rhsyns=%20) and [vb libary for creating pdf](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/visual-basic-tutorial-pdf-advanced). However I can not see how i can use any of these two sources to solve my problem. Has anyone done something similiar to this? Do i need to convert the PDF to PNG and then back again?
Below are a screenshot of the 3 sample signatures I would like to add to my PDF's.

Today the pdf is printed, then handed around and signed, then the signed version are scanned, emailed to me, and then i save it at the correct location. This is a lot of work, especially since you might go to the others office just to find out that the person is not there:) So i would like to try to do this from excel with vba, since the overview of the pdf's are there.

[image: Signing]

Comment: Do you know the location of the signature or it must be found on the run?

Comment: To have any editable forms, you need Usage Rights which can be done with Adobe software only. But this looks like a real signature from a scanned copy.

Comment: @Paulo Soares, yes we only use A3 as our formats of drawing and hence i know the exact postion of where to place the signature/initials

Answer (score 0):

The way I have always placed my signature on an electronic document is through MS Paint (as ignorant as that sounds).

1. Just open a paint file.
2. Sign the name big, and neat. Then sav the png.
3. Convert your pdf to a word document.
4. Place the signature. Scale the size down as appropriate.
5. Then export the document as a pdf.

Voila! You have just signed a document digitally. This may be one of the worse ways of doing this but it worked for me, and after you do it once the signature is saved and it is easy to replicate the process.

Comment: [A digital signature is a mathematical scheme for demonstrating the authenticity of a digital message or document... Digital signatures employ asymmetric cryptography.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) In no way your scheme has anything in common with digital signatures. It might be considered an [electronic signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_signature), though.

Comment: I believe you may be right. That is my mistake confusing the two. Thanks for the notice though. I will remove this post because it doesn't have any relevance

Comment: Considering the image the OP provided, it looks like he also confused the two. Thus, your answer still may help him... ;)

Comment: Thanks @mkl Electronic signature is what i meant, i edited the post title:)  So i need to convert my pdf to image and the back again instead of manipulating the PDF directly if i got you correctly Constunitine, how do i convert pdf to word from vba though?

Comment: Sorry, @skatun to the best of my knowledge there isn't a way to do this in VBA. That doesn't mean there isn't though. But to accomplish this the way I do, you need to convert the PDF to a Microsoft Word Document, place the image of the signature, then use Microsoft Word to export the file as a PDF.

Comment: I will lokk into converting a pdf to an image then. Thanks @Constuntine